# How to use mysql unix_timestamp() as the starting point for auto increment?

Tags: mysql, jpa, mysql-workbench

I would like to know if it is possible do create a table having the auto increment start with the value of the unix timestamp (the time of create of the table), i.e.

```
create table something(
    something_id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,
    something_name varchar(10) not null,
    something_random varchar(3) not null
) engine=InnoDB auto_increment=round(unix_timestamp(curtime(4)) * 1000);
```

Note that I can just replace `auto_increment=round(unix_timestamp(curtime(4)) * 1000)` with the value of `select round(unix_timestamp(curtime(4)) * 1000);`. But what I want is a way to do it automatically when creating my tables.

After reading [mysql select section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) everything I tried gave me a compiler error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to use a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) that does this.

Procedure that receives the table creation command and concatenates ([CONCAT function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)) the value of the expression at the end. Since the query is in string format, the [Prepared Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) is used to execute it.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `createTable`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE createTable(IN strCreateQuery TEXT)
BEGIN
        SET @query = CONCAT(strCreateQuery, " auto_increment=", ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4)) * 1000));

        PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Once created, simply execute the procedure with the creation query of the desired table.

```
CALL createTable("
create table something(
    something_id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,
    something_name varchar(10) not null,
    something_random varchar(3) not null
) engine=InnoDB");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Although I don't understand your solution as I am a beginner at mysql; may I ask for resources--if any--to further my reading?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering you. If you have not already seen, check the official documentation that I added as a link in the response. There you will see examples and more details.